# Using CARMEN Robot Navigation Toolkit with Hoyuko Laser

Tags: mapping, navigation, robotics, carmen

I'm currently working with CARMEN (http://carmen.sourceforge.net/), and I'm trying to make a robot navigate using the CARMEN toolkit and a Hoyuko URG-04LX. Even though the laser does work, and CARMEN reads the data (I checked running the CARMEN laserview, and it shows the laser scans), the "robot" module doesn't receive any data from the laser.

Has anyone managed to make the Hokuyo URG laser work with CARMEN?

Comment: Wow.. this seems really specialized. You might be better served with the CARMEN mailing lists: http://carmen.sourceforge.net/mailing_lists.html

Comment: Carmen Mailing Lists
This page needs to be updated! 


:)


Anyways, the problem was solved... how should I proceed? Shall I post the solution here? How do I close this thread? Thanks ! :)

Comment: Post your solution and then make it the answer to your problem.

Comment: @Pablo Hevia-Koch : What OS did you use to install Carmen ? Does it works with openSUSE 11.0 ?

Comment: @Arkapravo:

I used Debian, but it will probably work with openSUSE too :)

Comment: @Pablo Hevia-Koch : I have been trying with Ubuntu 9.10 and 9.04 (both are Debian based). Can you please tell me which version of CARMEN did you use and which Debian distro ?

Comment: @Arkapravo: Latest available version of CARMEN @ sourceforge (0.7.4-beta if I recall correctly) and the latest stable version of Debian. 

If you are having problems, post it as a question in StackOverflow and  i can answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to remove the "HOKUYO IN SCIP 2.0 MODE" from the sourcecode before compiling, and then manually setting SCIP2.0 mode everytime the laser starts. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is showing up in laserview, then there is nothing wrong with the laser.  Is the robot program connected to the central IPC server program as the laser program?  You can also try using the logger program to record the laser information to disk, this will allow you to check that they are actually flowing through the system.